# ScrollToFixed scrolling issue

Tags: jquery, css, scrollto, sidebar

I have a problem with scrollToFixed script. https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed
This is a case:http://dash.com.pl/CTP/gallery.html
This script works fine, but when I scroll down and after this scrolling up, appears a hole.

This is a script which gives limits:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.sidebar').scrollToFixed({
    marginTop: 0,
    limit: $('.footer').offset().top - $('.sidebar').height() - 20
});
});
```

Thank You for your help.

Comment: Would be helpful if you add an jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. That's a nice and cool plugin. I think i found a solution for this.

You can wrapp the using an div as show below.

**HTML**

```
<div id="sidebar-wrapper">
 <aside class="sidebar"></aside>
</div>
```

Then add css to float the div,

**CSS**

```
div#sidebar-wrapper{
 float:right;
}
```

This has to work!. Try this and let me know.

Comment: it works correctly on firefox now. but not on chrome :/ let me check again.

Comment: I cleaned my cache, and still bad. My browser is Chrome.

Comment: @Lukas give width:235px to the #sidebar-wrapper!! IT WORKS! :D

Comment: Wow, now is great, thank You so much. I have one more problem but not related to ScrollToFix. May I ask You for this?

Comment: @Lukas Glad to help you. yeah sure.. what is it?

Comment: Great, so please open this site http://dash.com.pl/CTP/index.html minimalize your browser and scroll horizontally right. You see that my background is bad filled. Do you know why?

Comment: @Lukas try adding `background:#3D3D3D` to `.footer`

Comment: What's wrong in top? can you post a screenshot or something please?

Comment: sorry mate cant figure out why its happening. Can't see anything wrong in my browsers. Pls see the screenshot http://i.imgur.com/zeuBMUg.png